# XCode 4.3 fonts and colors export

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3

I have created a fonts and colors theme for code editing in XCode 4.3 on my laptop that I am particularly happy with, and I would like to export this and then re-import it onto my desktop.

Since going to this new App version of XCode, I can't appear to find anything user preferences related in ~\Library any more.  Does anyone know where the fonts and colors setting is now stored, or how to export/import an XCode color theme?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The folder is still there it is just hidden in Lion. You need to copy the file using terminal or show hidden files by typing in terminal 'defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE'

The path is:
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes

Comment: Had no clue I had to needed to use terminal, was wondering why the heck I couldn't find it.  Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually have to use terminal, you can access that folder by using *"Go to Folder…"* in the *"Go"* menu in Finder's Menu Bar. The keyboard shortcut is <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

[image: The "Go" menu of Finder's Menu Bar, with "Go to Folder..." at the bottom.]

Paste  `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes` in the resulting dialog.

[image: The dialog resulting from clicking the indicated menu item.]

**Note:** this folder only exists once you add or duplicate a theme.